# Windows PowerShell ISE freezes on launch every time - how do I diagnose?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, freeze, powershell-ise

Every time I launch PowerShell ISE (x64 or x86), I get this:

[image: screenshot of partially rendered ISE window]

It is drawn exactly as shown and immediately unresponsive. The black part at the bottom is within the window boundaries.

PowerShell CLI runs just fine.

I see nothing in Event Viewer apart from a record of the app hanging when I attempt to close it.

I tried downloading the `GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont` font as part of Solution #3 at [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/53), but the download link appears to be broken.

I have no pending Windows Updates as of this post. I am running Windows 10 Pro 21H2.

[image]

How do I figure out what's going on?

---

**EDIT (2021-01-02T03:32Z):** Apparently it's just taking forever to start up. It eventually rendered, *10 minutes later*. If Visual Studio 2022 can open in less than 10 seconds, PS ISE has no excuse. What in the heck is going on?

Comment: Use a good task manager to seen if you can tell if a specific sub process is causing this. Also, what is in your PowerShell ISO profile?

Comment: For what it's worth, Windows has discontinued support for the venerable Command Prompt.  And Windows 10 has been moving away from the very dated PowerShell.  Windows 10 / 11 has finalized its new PowerShell to the very impressive Windows Terminal.  The beta was called Windows Terminal Preview.  I'm still using that beta version after nearly 2 years.

Comment: check to see if something is in one of the profiles that gets run when you start the ISE. take a look at `$profile | Select-Object -Property *` to see the list of all the profiles that apply to your ISE session.

Comment: That command printed 4 paths to files that don't exist, so I'm guessing no profile stuff. However, @music2myear, I did watch one of the executions in procmon yesterday and saw that it got slowed trying to access recent files on a network path-- something it loaded from an XML file. Deleting that file fixed the slowness. Posting as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell ISE was slow attempting to access the recent files list and having the connections repeatedly fail to access a network path that no longer existed. I solved it by deleting this directory:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\powershell_ise.exe_StrongName_lw2v2vm3wmtzzpebq33gybmeoxukb04w
```

I discovered this by running Sysinternals Process Monitor, filtering by PowerShell_ISE's PID, and looking at the last thing to happen before the rendering stopped. The last thing it did was to read the files in that directory. It then just reported "Thread Exit" for several minutes.

[image: screenshot of Process Monitor]

I store most of my files on a NAS, and for some reason had opened one or two files in ISE by IP, rather than through the mapped network drives. ISE was trying to resolve each of the files, and taking a really long time to time out.

Comment: thank you for the Answer ... i was quite curious about your problem. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

In my case what was slowing down the launch of the PowerShell ISE was the console history. It was an almost 2Gb file with many repeated commands. Deleting this file solved the problem:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt
```

I also discovered it using the Sysinternals Process Monitor mentioned earlier. It showed many accesses to this file.

Answer (score 0):

For us, what was slowing down the launch of the PowerShell ISE was because of the "Show Command Add-on".   When the Show Command Add-on is... on, it is similar to run a get-command.  Make sure to uncheck it, and next time you start ISE, it should be faster

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @J.D. Mallen.
In my case I had an autosave information stored in XML file in the following folder:

```
AppData\
Local\
Microsoft_Corporation\
powershell_ise.exe_StrongName_lw2v2vm3wmtzzpebq33gybmeoxukb04w\
3.0.0.0\
AutoSaveInformation
```

I deleted the XML file and now it's fine.